# Callbacks When an NSScrollView is Scrolled?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, uiscrollview, nsscrollview

I'm making a Mac app which needs to know when the user is scrolling the `NSScrollView`, however, I can't find any methods like `UIScrollView`, which has the following delegate methods:

```
– scrollViewDidScroll:
– scrollViewWillBeginDragging:
– scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:
– scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:
– scrollViewDidScrollToTop:
– scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:
– scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:
```

Can I have the similar delegate methods for the App Kit? Thanks in advance.

Kai.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can monitor a scroll view's changes by monitoring the bounds of it's content view.  First set the content view to post its changes with

```
[contentView setPostsBoundsChangedNotifications:YES];
```

Then register as an observer of those notifications with

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(boundsDidChange:) name:NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification object:contentView];
```

Comment: Note that his observer is also triggered when the scrolling is performed in code.

Comment: How do I know if the scroll has ended?

Answer (score 11):

Update for Swift 4:

```
scrollView.contentView.postsBoundsChangedNotifications
```

Also the call is:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(boundsChange),
                                       name: NSView.boundsDidChangeNotification,
                                       object: scrollView.contentView)
```

Edit: the collection in mac doesn't inherit from scrollview. updated properly

Comment: Upvoted too soon, it actually does not work as is. `CollectionView` is not a scroll view.

Comment: apologies, I copy pasted but this is really not the collection but a the scrollview content view

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem recently... To somewhat emulate deceleration callbacks it is possible to override

```
-(void) scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent
```

of NSScrollView class, but then check **theEvent.momentumPhase** instead of theEvent.phase for event phases.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @Sean Rich answer.

The `contentView` is the `NSClipView` between the `NSScrollView` and `NSCollectionView`.

[image: Picture of clip view from the Storyboard]

For this to work, both the `ClipView` needs to be set to `postsBoundsChangedNotifications` **and** should be passed in the notification object.

```
self.clipView.postsBoundsChangedNotifications = true

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(collectionViewDidScroll(notification:)),
                                       name: NSView.boundsDidChangeNotification,
                                       object: self.clipView)
```

Comment: Should there also be a subsequent removeObserver call? when the class is deInit ?

Comment: @eonist Good question. You do not need to remove observer in this call. From Apple: "If your app targets iOS 9.0 and later or macOS 10.11 and later, you do not need to unregister an observer that you created with this function" https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1415360-addobserver

Comment: thanks, almost like a callback then. You don't have to deregister them either

Answer (score 0):

my two cents for swift 4.2 OSX:

....

```
if let clipView = self.collectionView.superview, let sv = clipView.superview as? NSScrollView{

        let contentView = sv.contentView
        contentView.postsBoundsChangedNotifications = true

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(collectionViewDidScroll(notification:)),
                                               name: NSView.boundsDidChangeNotification,
                                               object: clipView)
}








 //MARK: scrollview observer:

    @objc func collectionViewDidScroll(notification: Notification){

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
NSScrollViewWillStartLiveScrollNotification
NSScrollViewDidLiveScrollNotification
NSScrollViewDidEndLiveScrollNotification

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(scrollViewDidScroll(_:)),
    name: NSScrollViewDidLiveScrollNotification,
    object: scrollView
)
```