# Make NSTableView scroll behave like UITableView scroll

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I want to make the NSTableView call height for row before it calls view for column on scroll. (Similar to what UITableView does). Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I really wonder why do you need it,because there can be an alternative for this.

You can first look at 
[Callbacks When an NSScrollView is Scrolled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169355/callbacks-when-an-nsscrollview-is-scrolled),
and then actually call noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged: which internally calls height for row.
I am just trying to help,but i highly suggest please don re invent the wheel.

Comment: In the table view the content for the row changes dynamically. Hence i need to recalculate the height of the rows everytime the user scrolls. Is there an easy method to get the index of the visible cells after scroll ?

Comment: Try looking into this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504546/view-based-nstableview-with-rows-that-have-dynamic-heights