# Are there any scroll events in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am building custom video player, but I need the funcionality of when i scroll from bottom, right, or left to load elements in new collection view, and also when I click again on screen to exit collection view. I am new to Swift, are there events built in Swift for this, and are there any libaries for that?

Comment: It's unclear whether you're on macOS or iOS, but, yes, collection views have scroll events. Search for "UICollectionView scroll event" or check here for NSCollectionView: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169355/callbacks-when-an-nsscrollview-is-scrolled

Comment: Sorry I am bad with English, I want to build player like youtube, you know when you pull from bottom of your screen on youtube you get other channels in collecitonView... How can i imitate that funcionality. I am building this app for ios. So to be clear i want to display another channels in colllection view when i scroll to up, from left to right and from right to left. I need those events. Hope you understand.